# Change-of-variables with a product of two functions in the integrand

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

How does the change-of-variable $x=\phi(t)$ formula
$$ \int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$$
look like when the integral looks like this:
$$\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(x) g(x) dx$$
I focussed on the product in the integrand, and tried using the product rule, as well as integration by parts, but both approaches led nowhere. Is this after all just $dx$ replaced by $\phi'(t)dt$ and then $\phi$ plugged in?, meaning
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(\phi(t)) \, g(\phi(t)) \, \phi'(t)dt$$
This sure feels like textbook material, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I mean... let $h(x):=f(x)g(x)$...

Comment: That sure crossed my mind, but doesn't this make additional assumptions about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? In other words: can one _always_ write $h(x)$ in place of this product?

Comment: it depends if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, riemann integrable then you have no restriction.

Comment: Oh, so if $h(x) := f(x)g(x)$ wasn't possible the integration wouldn't make sense in the first place? I see. Thanks.